# Losing access to variable after using parentheseless function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using a angular directive where I at one point assigns the function scalePoint (with parameters) using the parentheseless syntax. It seems like my function that I am assigning don't have access to anything that is not part of the scope of the function or that is passed as parameters. See example:

```
var Map = (function () {
    function Map(dataService, common, mapboxToken) {
        var _this = this;
        this.map = null;
    }

Map.prototype.initMap = function () {
    var _this = this;
    // Map is initalized, (code omitted)
    dataService.loadData().then(function (data) {
        var geoLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
            pointToLayer: _this.scalePoint // function assigned
        });
    });
};

Map.prototype.scalePoint = function (feature, latlng) {
    var zoom = this.map.getZoom(); // Map is undefined
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        color: "#fff"
    });
};
```

When I try to use my map variable it is undefined, I guess I could pass the map as a parameter to the scalePoint function, but I do not know how to do that. I am also wondering how it gets the values for "feature" and "latlng", all I know is that they are a part of data.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like this :

```
var Map = function (dataService, common, mapboxToken) {
    var _this = this;
    this.map = null;
}
```

This way you want get error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
var Map = (function () {
    function Map(dataService, common, mapboxToken) {
        this.dataService = dataService;
        this.common = common;
        this.mapboxToken = mapboxToken;
    }
    Map.prototype.initMap = function () {
        var _this = this;
        // Map is initalized, (code omitted)
        this.dataService.loadData().then(function (data) {
            var geoLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
                pointToLayer: _this.scalePoint
            });
        });
    };

    Map.prototype.scalePoint = function (feature, latlng) {
        var zoom = this.map.getZoom();
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            color: "#fff"
        });
    };
    return Map;
})();
```

This is valid JavaScript. Here you wrap your Map class in a self executing function and add the methods on the prototype.

However, your `map` field in the `scalePoint` method is still undefined, simply because you don't assign it anywhere else.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've omitted the code that assigns the map just to make thing simpler. I implemented your code, but I still do not get access to this.map though.

Comment: If the problem is in code you omitted, it's a little hard to help you :) Could you strip it down and show it to us?

Comment: Thanks again for helping me out, I appreciate it. The problem is not in the omitted code, because I have access to this.map everywhere else, the problem is where I set `pointToLayer : _this.scalePoint` that I call without passing any parameters. If anyone could explain how that works, and how the function get access to the parameters (feature, latlng) without me passing them in, I can figure the rest out myself :)